# cannot import user.key in network manager openvpn

Tags: openvpn

Using network manager `openvpn` I cannot import `client.key`. It doesn't show any `.key` files in the import dialogue. I can import the `ca.crt` and the `client.crt` which are in the same directory.
I copied the `client.key` to `client.pem` but the import dialogue doesn't see `.pem` files either.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it. All key files had a mask of 600. After I changed it I could import everything and my VPN works.